# Read local JSON file using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a code to read local JSON file in Javascript. The code I have written is given below:

```
    var xobj = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xobj.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xobj.open('GET', 'file:///C:/tmp/abc.json', true);
    xobj.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xobj.readyState == 4 && xobj.status == "200") {

            // .open will NOT return a value but simply returns undefined in async mode so use a callback
            callback(xobj.responseText);

        }
    }
    xobj.send(null);
```

Also, I am running Chrome browser using below command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security --allow-file-access-from-files
```

The code isn't working and I am receiving `xobj.status` as `0`. I have inspected Network tab and found out that `xhr` status for `abc.json` is shown in red as `'canceled'`.

Please let me know if I am mistaking anything.

Comment: Use 'fs' module and run .js file using Node.js

Comment: Please check for status 0 as when loading files locally with XMLHttpRequest, you don't get a status returned because it's not from a Webserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XMLHttpRequest will fetch resources from a server.

Your path

```
 'file:///C:/tmp/abc.json'
```

is not a url which is being served by a server

Moreover, with JavaScript you cannot have access to the operating system's storage drive.

To read a local file, you need to use a file uploader and read the contents of the uploaded file via the File API.

Try this

https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/